# Can I add Google Meet and Zoom to the "Add video call" dropdown in macOS Monterey's Calendar app?

Tags: macos, video, calendar, zoom-meeting, google-meet

The "New event" popup on macOS Monterey's Calendar app (see below) seems to suggest it is possible to add additional video calling services, to automatically create links for them when creating an event. FaceTime is the only built-in option. Is there a known way to add additional services (e.g. Zoom and Google Meet) yet?

[Screenshot: New event popup showing video calling services dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi7JV.png)